# WAMP urlencoded when running file_get_contents

Tags: wamp, file-get-contents, urlencode

I am calling an URL using file_get_contents on a WAMP server.

When i run the code i get an error of the site i am calling saying there is an invalid input, but when i run the same URL, that i use in the file_get_contents call, in the browser its working. For some reason file_get_contents makes & of the & there are in the URL. So it looks like it gets automaticly urlencoded?

Is this a problem of a setting in the WAMP enviroment or ...? The same code is running online and there it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to encode the URL in your PHP script if it contains non alpha-numeric characters. To encode a request in PHP script, use:

```
<?php
    $req=$_REQUEST['req'];
    $encoded_req= urlencode($req);
    echo $encoded_req;
?>
```